# How to order a ListView in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to order an already existing `ListView`?

I want to order a list by the information that I only receive after the `ListView` is built. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Reorder items in the list `ListView` renders and then re-render ListView by calling `setState(...)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `StreamBuilder` to achieve that.

Here is the example of doing it.

```
Widget buildStream() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: your_stream_here,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // return your preferred widget like a ListTile
        } else {
          // show a progress indicator to user like CircularProgressIndicator
        }
      },
    );
}
```

If you data only changes once, it's better to use `FutureBuilder` in that case.

Here is an example

```
Widget buildFuture() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: your_future_here,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // return your preferred widget like a Text
        } else {
          // show a progress indicator to user like CircularProgressIndicator
        } 
      },
    );
  }
```